# Python use API to get data

Tags: python

I am kind of stuck in trying to solve following issue: I try to access a web-page in order to get some data for a supplier (need to do it for work) in an automated way, using an API.

The API is called https://wl-api.mf.gov.pl and shall provide information stored in JSON for supplier which can be found over their tax ID.

I use the request package and I am able to manage to get positive response:

```
import requests
nip=7393033097
response=requests.get("https://wl-api.mf.gov.pl")
print(response) --> Response [200]
```

If I click on the link and scroll until I find the specific part for the tax information, I find the following line

```
GET /api/search/nip/{nip}
```

So what I did is to add this line into my response variable, since this is how I understood it - and there is the point where I think I am wrong

```
response=requests.get("https://wl-api.mf.gov.pl/search/7393033097/{7393033097}")
```

However, I cannot access it.
Am I doing something wrong - I do believe yes - and can anyone give me a little help :)

Update: If I check the requirements / documentation I find following information where I need a bit support to implement it

```
GET /api/search/nip/{nip}

(nip?date)
Single entity search by nip

**Path parameters**
nip (required)
*Path Parameter — Nip*

**Query parameters**
date (required)
*Query Parameter — format: date*

**Return type**
EntityResponse
Example data
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: I believe you should write to  WykazPodatnikow@mf.gov.pl for more information on request formats.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line:`https://wl-api.mf.gov.pl/search/7393033097/{7393033097}` should be like this:

```
https://wl-api.mf.gov.pl/search/nip/7393033097
```

Comment: it gives me the following information "Niepoprawne żądanie" which means invalid request

Comment: Maybe you forgot `date` parameter. I just read lightly the doc.

Comment: Indeed https://wl-api.mf.gov.pl/#nip?date
Following is written


Path parameters
nip (required)

Path Parameter — Nip
Query parameters

date (required)
Query Parameter — format: date
Any suggestion how I could implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

*https://wl-api.mf.gov.pl/api/search/nip/7393033097?date=2023-07-03*

As per the documentaion this date format is required from January 10, 2020.

Best regards